# Not able to start with asmack

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
        SmackAndroid.init(this);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }

        ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(HOST, PORT, SERVICE);
        XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);
    }
```

this code is showing error "Cannot instantiate the type XMPPConnection"
in eclipse with red underline

for following line:

```
XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);
```

I am using asmack-android-8-4.0.0-rc2.jar,
smack-resolver-dnsjava-4.0.0.jar as libs

Comment: I also want to use asmack but always getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackAndroid. do you have any workaround? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I remember correctly latest versions of ASmack require you to use a subclass of XMPPConnection and not the class itself. The fact that XMPPConnection can still has a public constructor is indeed misleading...

Try using [XMPPTCPConnection](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/dailybuilds/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/tcp/XMPPTCPConnection.html) instead:

Instead of:

```
XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);
```

Use this:

```
XMPPTCPConnection conn = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);
```

Comment: I followed docs here https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/overview.html and they messed up. thanks for help.